# How to change focus on buttons up, down, left and right relative to the button that is selected?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm new in programming.

I don't know how to explain well!!.

How can i make my WinForms application understand the button location,
for example imagine a number of buttons positioned and that one of them is select

button1- button2 -button3

button4-(button5)-button6

button7 -button8- button9

how can i press down on the keyboard and jump to (button8) and not to (button6), or press upkey and go from (button2).
how can i make visual studio understand which button is *up* or *down* or *left* and *right* relative to the button that is selected?

Comment: I don't understand. What does this have to do with `Visual Studio`?

Comment: What buttons are you talking about ? In Visual Studio ? In Forms Designer ? In WPF ? WebForms ?

Comment: It's windows form, i'm trying to do a GUI with visual studio,

Comment: Ok, you don't want Visual Studio to "understand it" you want your application to do something. override the "OnKeyDown" of you Form, handle the Keys.Down Key, and than you can implement some logic "if current button=5 and Key=down then select 8". Of course the latter needs some systematics, but first do the event handling.

Comment: You can probably modify the answer to this question to get it to work with buttons instead of textboxes. I should think the concept is the same.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909291/how-to-move-the-cursor-between-textboxes-using-arrows

Comment: Search for MVC pattern, buttons are views not model.
Build up a real model who store the selected *cell* coordinates and a controller who can provide the coordinate of the *cells* in each of the four directions.
Visual studio is an IDE : just a fancy text editor to write and compile code, it doesn't "understand" anything.

Comment: I have removed the Visual Studio tag.  Per the description of the tag, that tag is only for questions about visual studio itself.  It is not for questions about code written using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your Buttons to a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel), so each Button's position is determined by the TableLayoutPanel's (`Column:Row`) coordinates.

- Create a TableLayoutPanel (in the below, named **`tlpButtons`**) with enough Rows and Columns to contain your Buttons. You can add/remove Rows and Column at run-time, if needed.
- Select all your Buttons and subscribe to the [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown), using the PropertyGrid in the Form Designer, so that you have just one event handler for all your Buttons (in this code, the event handler is named **`buttons_PreviewKeyDown`**).
- When the `Key.Up` or `Keys.Down` are pressed, the `PreviewKeyDown` handler of the Buttons is invoked. The sender argument references the control that triggered the event, so we cast `sender` to `Control` (since only a Control type reference is needed, we don't use any property specific to a derived type, like `Button`)
- If we handle the Key pressed, we have to set [IsInputKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.isinputkey), otherwise the event is passed on to the control and processed (causing the normal selection to trigger)
- The TableLayoutPanel's [GetPositionFromControl()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getpositionfromcontrol) returns the Row/Column position of this Control.
- We just set the Row value `± 1`, depending on what cursor Key has been pressed (while checking whether the new value is in the `[0 : RowsCount]` range).
  The [GetControlFromPosition()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcontrolfromposition) method returns the reference of the control in the new position: we use this reference to set the current [ActiveControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol).

This is the result:

[image: Button PreviewKeyDown]

---

Note:
the **`buttons_PreviewKeyDown`** event handler is the same for all Buttons/Controls.
**`tlpButtons`** is the name of the TableLayoutPanel used as container for the Buttons/Controls

Updated to also work with a Numeric Pad when either active or inactive.

```
private void buttons_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Control;
    var pos = tlpButtons.GetPositionFromControl(btn);
    bool moveFocus = false;

    switch (e.KeyCode) {
        case Keys.NumPad8:
        case Keys.Up:
            pos.Row = (pos.Row > 0) ? pos.Row - 1 : tlpButtons.RowCount - 1;
            moveFocus = true;
            break;
        case Keys.NumPad2:
        case Keys.Down:
            pos.Row = (pos.Row < (tlpButtons.RowCount - 1)) ? pos.Row + 1 : 0;
            moveFocus = true;
            break;
        case Keys.NumPad4:
            if (pos.Column > 0) {
                pos.Column -= 1;
            }
            else {
                pos.Column = tlpButtons.ColumnCount - 1;
                pos.Row = pos.Row > 0 ? pos.Row - 1 : tlpButtons.RowCount - 1;
            }
            moveFocus = true;
            break;
        case Keys.NumPad6:
            if (pos.Column < (tlpButtons.ColumnCount - 1)) {
                pos.Column += 1;
            }
            else {
                pos.Column = 0;
                pos.Row = (pos.Row < tlpButtons.RowCount - 1) ? pos.Row + 1 : 0;
            }
            moveFocus = true;
            break;
    }
    if (moveFocus) {
        e.IsInputKey = true;
        var ctrl = tlpButtons.GetControlFromPosition(pos.Column, pos.Row);
        if (ctrl != null) this.ActiveControl = ctrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about buttons within a Form.

Put them in a List like that

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>() {Button1, Button2...}
```

Now you know what button you are on and going up means you need to take the current index and substract **3*** from it (Button6 -> Button3) and just use that as the new index for the list.
For down you add **3*** and left/right are minus/plus 1.

Now you just have to define your edge cases: 
What if you press down or right when you are on Button9?

> *This value changes based on the amount of columns. 3 columns => +/-3; 4 col => +/-4

Comment: It should probably be noted that this will only work for the exact configuration of columns OP has specified. If they add a new column that maths would need to be modified.

Comment: That is correct, I added a note to reflect that issue

Comment: typo - new List<string> (new List<Button>