# TableLayoutPanel loop (C# forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3x3 grid with labels in every cell and Text "X" in each and every one. When I click on one of these labels, I want the one and the one next to it to change the text to "O" by using foreach loop of controls (rows and columns). Does anyone have an idea of what it would have to look like?

Comment: Why do you want to use a `foreach` loop?  Is that what the homework assignment says to do?

Comment: *the one next to it*, are up to 8 other Labels.

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666527/7444103) (it's pretty simple code) to determine which is the *next cell* (or the previous one, or those above and below, or the first one (or last one) of the first (or last) *line* or *column* if the position *overflows*).

Comment: @MikeH I'm making battleships and this is a phase where player needs to lay ships and from what I found out foreach loop seems to be an easy way to do it but if you can think of easier way I am open to suggestions. I also tried to define what happens when every single label is clicked but it is just so ..dull

Comment: @Jimi thanks I sure will check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly not a full solution, but maybe it'll give you an idea on how to start.

To create the labels, you'll certainly want to do that programatically:

```
  for (int col = 0; col < table.ColumnCount; col++)
  {
    for (int row = 0; row < table.RowCount; row++)
    {
      Label lbl = new Label();
      lbl.Click += Lbl_Click;
      table.Controls.Add(lbl, col, row);
    }
  }
```

Note that the click event is the same for every label.  Within that event you can get information about the label that was clicked:

```
private void Lbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Label lbl = (Label)sender;
  int row = table.GetRow(lbl);
  int col = table.GetColumn(lbl);

  lbl.Text = "O";

  //This is just an example
  //This will throw an error if you click the rightmost cell
  Label lbl2 = (Label)table.GetControlFromPosition(col+1,row);
  lbl2.Text = "O"; 

}
```