# Change focus on a Button in a Panel using the arrow keys

Tags: vb.net, winforms, focus

Assume you have a Form with ten Buttons on it, with the first one having the focus, so that it can be clicked by hitting the Enter key on the keyboard.  Now, you can set the focus to the next button simply by pressing the Down arrow key. This works out of the box.

Then I constrain this functionality to the first three Buttons on the Form.
So, when the third Button on the Form has the focus and I press the Down arrow key, the first Button - instead of the forth button - should receive the focus.

Question:
how can I change the focus to another button outside the Panel with arrow key?

Comment: It would be better if you picked just one language.  Not VB and C#.

Comment: sorry, what about VB

Comment: [How to change focus on buttons up, down, left and right relative to the button that is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666527/7444103)

Comment: Your description of the functionality you're after is not completely clear. Possibly, add some other detail, related to how these Buttons are grouped and how the focus is expected to move between the groups of Buttons.

Comment: thanks for the answer @jimi